# Running root script upon ssh'ing as a particular user, but not upon standard login

Tags: ssh, iptables, scripting, shell-scripting

I would like to do the following :

If I login as user ABC via the login screen, do nothing. However if I ssh as ABC, then I want to run a root script, without being prompted for roots password, and without having to store roots password somewhere on the disk.

The motivation for this is outlined in the article in [Linux : restricting outgoing on an application basis](https://serverfault.com/questions/344756/linux-restricting-outgoing-on-an-application-basis) . Basically, inspired by the article https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/how-to-restrict-internet-access-for-a-particular-user-on-the-lan-using-iptables , what I want to do is the following :

1)Login as user EFG and use firefox to access the web.

2)ssh into ABC.

3)Upon ssh'ing into ABC, I want to run the a script which emulates "sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --uid-owner 1234 -j DROP" where 1234 is the UID of user ABC

4)Then start using, under the ssh'ed terminal for ABC, all the applications which I do not want to have internet access, whilst still logged in as user EFG, hence allowing me to surf the internet as EFG.

Note I tried messing around the /etc/network/interfaces file, however I had some problems with the computer not being able to start properly if the computer was not connected to the network.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a [forced command](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current#sshrc) against an SSH key.

Create an SSH key for the user with `ssh-keygen` and add the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for user ABC, prefixing it with `command="/some/script"`

The script can contain the `sudo` commands you want to run and then `exec` a shell if needed.